# Mysql installation on docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to run mysql into modified ubuntu image which includs installation of  Node.js and basic mysql installation using below docker file

```
# Memcached

# use the ubuntu base image provided by dotCloud
FROM ubuntu/mysqlbase
MAINTAINER Hitesh

# make sure the package repository is up to dat//e
#RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
#RUN apt-get update

#RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
#ENTRYPOINT ["wc", "-l"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "running"]
ENTRYPOINT mysqld_safe & sleep 10
#RUN mysql
RUN echo "[mysqld]"                       >/etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
RUN echo "bind-address   = 0.0.0.0"      >>/etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
RUN echo "innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC" >>/etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
RUN echo "skip-name-resolve"             >>/etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
RUN echo "init_file = /etc/mysql/init"   >>/etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
RUN echo "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%'" >/etc/mysql/init

USER root

EXPOSE 3306
```

On running this server using below command

```
sudo docker run -p 3306:13306 mysql/dockerfiletest
```

Following error was encountered

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Can some one please suggest what is needed to be changed here. I want to use this container to be linked with other container which is essentially running my node.js app.

Comment: I think you need to add `-d` to make it run in daemon mode? Not sure though

Comment: Adding -d worked and opened the port 11211 but it went down after 10 seconds. any idea why?

Comment: I am not sure how you use this container - you are exposing memcached port, you are running mysql server and installing mysql client? Do you  want to connect to your mysql server (in docker container) from outside/host? You should expose mysql port then.

Comment: got mixed up with ports. corrected now.

Comment: @Jiri: This actually worked when i corrected the ports. Would be glad to accept the answer if you can post it as. Thanks!

Comment: @Hitesh - thanks! I updated the answer a bit, so you can accept it - but it doesnt make too much sense  now - you have working code in your question now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You should check exposed port number - in your example is(was) port for memcached (11211) and not the port for mysql (3306).

---

Anyway, I think that you may need to modify your Dockerfile - remove unnecessary sleep in entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"]
```

Then you should start your container this way (daemon mode):

```
root@machine:/# docker run -d -p 3306:<host port> <image id>
```

Comment: Anyway I tried to build docker image with my modification without sleep and it works well. I can connect to mysqld from host without problems.

Comment: Thanks Jiri to point that out, Sleep here is just ensuring that mysqld_safe is done which might not be necessary as you pointed out. My issue was because of messed up between memcache and mysql ports which is sorted now.

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't that command expose port 3306 on the localhost to the <host port> on the container? Shouldn't port 3306 on the container be forwarded to some port on the host if the point is to connect to MySQL running on the container via the localhost?

Comment: @Mark Yep, you are corect the first port is host port and second port is container port.

Answer (score 2):

answer has already been accepted, but i think you could leave the sleep in your entrypoint if you change the '&' to '&&'. not sure if docker does any parsing of the entrypoint or just executes it, but bash treats '&' very differently than '&&'.

```
ENTRYPOINT mysqld_safe && sleep 10
```

Comment: a few things: it's "race condition", and i wasn't saying the sleep would fix the issue. i was pointing out (correctly) that `&` is likely not what OP wanted -- for that, he should use `&&`

Comment: OK agree with that